# How can I test that a before filter is in place on several controllers/actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have several 'admin' controllers, all of which inherit from AdminController, which has a before filter that restricts access to admins only.

I want my functional tests to check that only admins can access every action of every controller that is part of my admin system. What is the most succinct way to do this?

(I'm using the standard built-in test/unit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most succinct way would be through metaprogramming:

```
AdminController.subclasses.each do |controller|
  describe controller do
    controller.action_methods.each do |action_method|
      it "redirects non-admin user on #{action_method}" do
        get action_method
        assert_redirected_to home_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You'll have to handle gets vs. posts, and there's probably some typos, but hopefully that gives you something to start. (Also, this is using the minispec syntax. You'll have to translate a bit for test/unit.)

I'd probably recommend just adding the simple tests on a controller-by-controller basis, but this is probably a good integration test just to make sure you don't miss any.

Comment: Thanks, AdminController.subclasses and controller.action_methods were what I needed. I created an `http_method_for_action(action)` method to guess which http method should be used.